# How to get an array from arrays

Tags: groovy

I have an arrays

```
Object[][] arrays= [
    [country:USA, history:N, state:IL, zip:61523, phone:3090000000, id:3358897, lastName:BOYLE, billing:Y, address2:null, firstName:PAUL F , email:energyroofing1@XyZ, address1:PO BOX 507, city:CHILLICOTHE],
    [country:USA, history:N, state:IL, zip:61523, phone:3090000000, id:6372385, lastName:BOYLE, billing:N, address2:null, firstName:PAUL F , email:energyroofing1@xyz, address1:PO BOX 507, city:CHILLICOTHE]
]
```

in return i want array which is having billing:Y

Comment: What you have tried?  Please add the code and what errors you had so we can improve on it.

Comment: seems it's array of maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. Also, your data appears to be an array of maps, not an array of arrays, unless the child arrays actually contain elements that are the literal strings "country:USA", for example?

However, assuming you mean that you want an array containing all the maps from the original array where `billing` is set to `Y`, then you would do:

```
def arrays = [
    [country:"USA", history:"N", state:"IL", zip:"61523", billing:"Y" ],
    [country:"USA", history:"N", state:"CA", zip:"61999", billing:"N" ]
]

def billingSetToY = arrays.grep { it["billing"] == 'Y' }

assert billingSetToY.size() == 1
assert billingSetToY[0]["state"] == "IL"
```

If you're looking for something else, please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: or use `arrays.find{ it.billing=="Y" }` to find exactly one